# Having trouble with D3v4 update pattern with 3 levels of nested data

Tags: d3.js, merge, nested, updates

I have data nested into 3 levels, which I need to dynamically update.  The kicker is that the elements for the mid-level need to actually display on TOP of the elements for the low-level due to some hover behavior I need, so I'm having trouble with what the enter/update/exit/merge pattern should look like.  (There don't need to be any elements displayed for the high-level).

The code I have right now updates the data successfully but is not rendering the rectangles at all, instead giving me an error, `Uncaught TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function`.

How do I fix this problem, please?

Here's what it should look like before updating:

[image]

And here's what it should look like after updating:

[image]

[Here's a CodePen with the code Below](https://codepen.io/callmedeeray/pen/rEpGqb)

````js
```
let width = 0.9 * window.innerWidth,
 height = 0.9 * window.innerHeight,
 colors = ['darkviolet', 'steelblue', 'coral', 'Turquoise', 'firebrick', 'mediumslateblue', 'palevioletred', 'green', 'aqua'];

let data1 = 
 [{"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"1"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"2"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"3"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"4"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"5"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"6"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"7"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"8"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"9"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"1"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"2"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"3"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"4"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"5"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"6"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"7"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"8"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"9"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"1"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"2"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"3"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"4"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"5"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"6"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"7"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"8"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"9"}],
 
data2 = 
 [{"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"1"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"8","item":"2"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"9","item":"3"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"4"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"5"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"6"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"5","item":"7"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"8"},
  {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"9"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"1"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"2"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"7","item":"3"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"4"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"5"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"6"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"7"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"8"},
  {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"9"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"1"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"2"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"3","item":"3"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"4"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"5"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"6"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"7"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"6","item":"8"},
  {"group":"C","segment":"1","item":"9"}]; 

let button = d3.select('body')
.append('button')
.attr('type', 'button')
.style('display', 'block')
.text('Update')
.on('click', function() { update(data2) });

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.append('g');

let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(colors);


update(data1);

function getxy(data) {

let grouped = Array.from(d3.group(data, d=> d.group, d=> d.segment), ([key, value]) => ({key, value}));

grouped.forEach(function(s) {
 s.value = Array.from(s.value, ([key, value]) => ({key, value}));
 s.value.forEach(function(d) {
  d.start = d3.min(d.value, function(t) { t.segment = +t.segment; t.item = +t.item; return +t.item });
  d.end = d3.max(d.value, function(t) { return t.item });
  d.key = +d.key;
  d.group = s.key;
 })
})

let x1 = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
 .range([width*0.05, width])
 .padding(0.0);

let y1 = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(['A', 'B', 'C'])
 .range([10, height])
 .padding(0.1);

return [x1, y1, grouped];

}

function update(data) {
let xy = getxy(data);
let x = xy[0], y = xy[1], groupedData = xy[2];


let barsAll = svg
 .selectAll('.bars')
 .data(groupedData);

barsAll.exit().remove();

let barsEnter = barsAll
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .attr('class', 'bars');

barsEnter = barsEnter.merge(barsAll);

let segmentsAll = barsEnter
 .selectAll('.segments')
 .data(function(d) { return d.value });

segmentsAll.exit().remove();
 
let segmentsEnter = segmentsAll.enter();

let bitsAll = segmentsEnter
 .selectAll('.bits')
 .data(function(d) { return d.value });

bitsAll.exit().remove();

let bitsEnter = bitsAll
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
 .attr('class', 'bits')
 .attr('r', width*0.05)
 .attr('stroke', 'none');

bitsEnter = bitsEnter.merge(bitsAll);

bitsEnter
 .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.item) })
 .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()/2 })
 .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.segment) });

 
segmentsEnter.append('rect')
 .attr('stroke', 'black')
 .attr('class', 'segments')
 .style('fill-opacity', 0.2);

segmentsEnter = segmentsEnter.merge(segmentsAll);

segmentsEnter
 .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.key) })
 .attr('height', y.bandwidth()*0.75)
 .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.start) - width*0.05 })
 .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()*0.125 })
 .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.end) - x(d.start) + width*0.1 });
}
```
````

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, by going around the “merge” step on the mid-level segments and low-level bits (but not on the top-level bars), I was able to hack a fix, finally.  [Working pen](https://codepen.io/callmedeeray/pen/zVpJEP?editors=0010)

Still open to help from others because I feel like I should really get the hang of the whole flow - update, enter, exit, merge - at some point.

```js
let width = 0.9 * window.innerWidth,
  height = 0.9 * window.innerHeight,
  colors = ['darkviolet', 'steelblue', 'coral', 'Turquoise', 'firebrick', 'mediumslateblue', 'palevioletred', 'green', 'aqua'];


let data1 = 
  [{"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"1"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"2"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"3"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"4"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"5"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"6"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"7"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"8"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"9"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"1"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"2"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"3"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"4"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"5"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"6"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"7"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"8"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"9"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"1"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"2"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"3"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"4"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"5"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"6"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"7"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"8"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"9"}],
  
 data2 = 
  [{"group":"A","segment":"1","item":"1"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"8","item":"2"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"9","item":"3"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"4"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"5"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"2","item":"6"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"5","item":"7"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"8"},
   {"group":"A","segment":"3","item":"9"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"1"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"4","item":"2"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"7","item":"3"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"4"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"5"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"6"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"5","item":"7"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"8"},
   {"group":"B","segment":"6","item":"9"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"1"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"7","item":"2"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"3","item":"3"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"4"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"5"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"8","item":"6"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"9","item":"7"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"6","item":"8"},
   {"group":"C","segment":"1","item":"9"}]; 

let button = d3.select('body')
 .append('button')
 .attr('type', 'button')
 .style('display', 'block')
 .text('Update')
 .on('click', function() { update(data2) });

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('width', width)
 .attr('height', height)
 .append('g');

let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(colors);

function getxy(data) {
 
 let grouped = Array.from(d3.group(data, d=> d.group, d=> d.segment), ([key, value]) => ({key, value}));
 
 grouped.forEach(function(s) {
  s.value = Array.from(s.value, ([key, value]) => ({key, value}));
  s.value.forEach(function(d) {
   d.start = d3.min(d.value, function(t) { t.segment = +t.segment; t.item = +t.item; return +t.item });
   d.end = d3.max(d.value, function(t) { return t.item });
   d.key = +d.key;
   d.group = s.key;
  })
 })
 
 let x1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
  .range([width*0.05, width])
  .padding(0.0);

 let y1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(['A', 'B', 'C'])
  .range([10, height])
  .padding(0.1);
 
 return [x1, y1, grouped];

}

function update(data) {
 let xy = getxy(data);
 let x = xy[0], y = xy[1], groupedData = xy[2];

 // update
 let barsAll = svg
  .selectAll('.bars')
  .data(groupedData);
 
 // exit
 barsAll.exit().remove();
 
 // enter
 let barsEnter = barsAll
  .enter();
 
 barsEnter = barsEnter.merge(barsAll).append('g');
 
 barsEnter.selectAll('.segments').remove();
 
 d3.selectAll('.segments').remove();
 
 let segmentsAll = barsEnter
  .selectAll('.segments')
  .data(function(d) { return d.value });
 
 segmentsAll.exit().remove();
  
 let segmentsEnter = segmentsAll
  .enter();
 
 let bitsAll = segmentsEnter
  .selectAll('.bits')
  .data(function(d) { return d.value });
 
 bitsAll.exit().remove();
 
 bitsAll
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'bits')
  .attr('r', width*0.05)
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.item) })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()/2 })
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.segment) });
 
// bitsEnter = bitsEnter.merge(bitsAll);
 
 bitsAll
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.item) })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()/2 })
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.segment) });

 segmentsEnter
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'segments')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .style('fill-opacity', 0.2)
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.key) })
  .attr('height', function() { return y.bandwidth()*0.75 })
  .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.start) - width*0.05 })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()*0.125 })
  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.end) - x(d.start) + width*0.1 });
 
 segmentsAll
  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.key) })
  .attr('height', function() { return y.bandwidth()*0.75 })
  .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.start) - width*0.05 })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()*0.125 })
  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.end) - x(d.start) + width*0.1 });
 
 //segmentsAll = segmentsEnter.merge(segmentsAll);

 // segmentsEnter
 //  .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.key) })
 //  .attr('height', function() { return y.bandwidth()*0.75 })
 //  .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.start) - width*0.05 })
 //  .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.group) + y.bandwidth()*0.125 })
 //  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.end) - x(d.start) + width*0.1 });
  
}
update(data1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```